# Android: Relative layout for Row.xml

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-relativelayout

I tried many times to draw a relative layout like shown in the image below. But not succeed.
[image]

I design the image with paint to explain a bit better what i mean.
Any suggestions?

Comment: It seems you need 3 LinearLayouts to do this and play with weights appropriately.

Comment: I'm new to android. I have tried my best but no success. Thats why i have posted the question.

Comment: I posted an answer that contains the layout I suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (it's the layout I proposed first in my comment):

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20"
        />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="40"
        />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20"
        />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
        />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

To make it more usable (i.e.: to assign contents dynamically), give these TextViews some ids (**android:id="@+id/txtSomething"**).

Obvoiusly, you can use any other control instead of TextViews: Buttons, ImageViews, in any combination.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following idea:

Root - linear layout (vertical) with 2 childs

first child - linear layout (horizontal) with weights according to your UI
second child - linear layout (horizontal) with weight 1 for its 2 childs.

Answer (score 0):

you can use TableLayout also...but it is complicated..
A tablelayout with 2 rows out of which first row has 4 childs and second row has 2childs...